# the name door does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I am writing a little console program that asks for name and age and then determines if you're old enough to proceed. I tried using a variable to determine if the person could proceed:

```
Bool door = true;
```

Then I wanted to ask the persons who were denied because of their age if they want to fill it in again.

```
if (door == false){
  Console.WriteLine("Wilt u op nieuw uw leeftijd invullen?");
}
```

But Visual Studio gives me the following error:

> Error CS0103 The name 'door' does not exist in the current context    ConsoleApplication1

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Hallo, wie ben jij? ");
            string Name = Convert.ToString (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Hallo " + Name + ", hoe oud ben jij? ");
            int Age = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine();

            if (Age < 18) {
                int remaining = 18 - Age;
                Console.WriteLine("Helaas bent u nog geen achttien, U moet nog:       "+remaining+" Jaar wachten.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            } else if (Age == 18) {
                Console.WriteLine("U mag net door");
                bool door = true;
                Console.ReadLine();
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("U bent door naar de volgende ronde");
                bool door = true;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (door == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wilt u op nieuw uw leeftijd invullen?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: door is defined inside an if-else statement; then it is used outside that statement.  Define it within the scope of the class (not in any loops/if statements)

Comment: Welkom in de wereld van C # !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each pair of curly braces `{ ... }` defines a **scope** in C#. That means that everything declared in that area is local to that area. That means that when you do:

```
{
  Console.WriteLine("U mag net door");
  bool door = true;
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

the area where the `door` variable lives, is restricted with the closed curly brace, and it does not exist anywhere else. When you try to use it afterwards, in `if (door == false)`, in a place where a variable called `door` does not exist, and has never existed, the compiler basically tells you that.

You will need to declare your variable beforehand, something like

```
bool door = false;
if (Age < 18){
  //....
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("U bent door naar de volgende ronde");
   door = true;
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

to be able to use it throughout your program.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation! Great to see that there are so much people out here who promote improving by doing this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your "door" variable is declared in scope of the if statement. Move it out of the if statement and declare at the top of the main.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the `door` variable in the `else` block. So at your `if` block, it is out of scope. What you can do is declare it at a scope both blocks can access. That is, directly inside the `Main` method

Answer (score 1):

Because bool door is created in a different scope determined through { } it does not exist in the outer scope. Move the variable out of the scope and it should work fine.